# "Key thob" and "key fob"

Tags: pronunciation, errors

I've been receiving emails at work inquiring about registering our key fobs. This is slightly disturbing to me as I've always called it a *key thob*. An internet search for *thob* tells me I really mean *fob*, but if I force it to search for *thob* instead, it finds plenty of results (1.1 million for *thob* compared to 7.7 for *fob*).

Is *thob* considered incorrect? Is it recognized? Is it obsolete? Or are some people just making up words by calling it a *thob*?

Comment: This is ridiculous. I find millions of records for key thob, and it being used in context in many places. Google search: http://www.google.com/search?q=key+thob&nfpr=1 Please vote to re-open this.

Comment: And it's definiately not too localized. I'm from halfway across the country, but when I ask my coworkers about it, 3 of the 11 asked say they use thob instead of fob. So it's definitely not 'too localized'.

Comment: @glowcoder: When I Googled *quotated* **"key fob"** it first claimed *About 5410 results*, but on scrolling through I find there are actually [only 484](https://www.google.com/search?q=key+thob&nfpr=1#q=%22key+thob%22&hl=en&pwst=1&nfpr=1&prmd=imvns&ei=BUfETsijMtPJ8gPozsWACw&start=480&sa=N&fp=1&biw=1138&bih=874&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&cad=b). I can only assume it's something to do with mis-hearing, but it's far more results than I would have expected. So - here's my apology. I'm voting to reopen in case someone can explain why this error happens.

Comment: btw - I expect the fact that **three** of your coworkers say "thob" is because you all work together, and pick up the error from each other. So it's not "statistically" significant.

Comment: Paging through the results finds 620 results for "key fob" vs. 491 for "key thob", with similar pages omitted. If you tell it to return all pages, both searches go to the maximum 100 pages without running out of results. I think we can safely say that this is *not* a localized mispronunciation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't believe I have been here long enough to have "transmitted my vocabularic disease to them". :)

Comment: @JasperLoy: Oh, there's no question that "fob" is correct and "thob" is a misspelling/mispronunciation. The question is, where does "thob" come from, and why is it (apparently) so common?

Comment: @glowcoder: Fair enough. But those other three might have a common origin, even if your usage isn't part of that. I just mean it's almost certainly not an error that 25% of all English speakers make, so your office is a "pocket" of high prevalence. I think Martha's 620:491 ratio must be a Google search quirk of some kind because I'm sure the erroneous usage can't possibly account for over 40% of the total, but as I said before, there's definitely something to be looked into here.

Comment: ... **two** things, actually, since I now have to spend effort figuring out why Google does this. Or maybe *three*, if I also want to know how to avoid being misled by it! :)

Comment: Note that searches for key thob without the quotes find mostly pages with both "key" and "thob" but not together.  The first ten pages are misleading.

Comment: @cindi I'm from Michigan, currently in Oregon, where 2 of the 3 are from. The other is from India (which surprised the jeepers out of me, because most Indian guys I know make a point of having perfect grammar!)

Comment: Sometimes I have a hard time getting the RFID sensor to recognize me and open the door.  At times like that, I'm tempted to thob in frustration...

Comment: @MT_Head What a thorry excuthe.

Comment: @corsiKa - You're right: I meant "fruthtration".  Thorry about dat.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As discussed above, this is clearly an error. However, it is an *interesting* error, which is driven by several different things:

1. The word *fob* is very rare, and is essentially unused outside of this expression and the idiomatic verb *to fob off*. Therefore it's not surprising that some people mis-acquire the word, since they have so few chances to correct themselves.
2. The sounds for *th* and *f* are acoustically very similar, and it is not difficult to mishear *f* as *th*. For a demonstration of this, see [page 13 of this paper](http://www.ling.cam.ac.uk/mark/Jones_2005_COPIL2.pdf) showing nearly identical frequency graphs for *f* and *th* [θ].
3. Because of #2, there are several English dialects where *f* is a frequent substitution for *th*, e.g. *think* is pronounced as *fink*. Speakers of these dialects have extra trouble knowing when to write *f* and when to write *th*, so many of the errors that you can find may be from people for whom *fob* and *thob* are actually pronounced identically. These people probably **say** *fob*, but mistakenly believe that the proper spelling is "thob".
4. Finally, the characteristic errors of the dialects in #3 prompt a hyper-correction from some people, causing them to "correct" *f* back to *th* in places where the *f* was actually correct. So some of the instances of *thob* may be due to people thinking that *fob* is a mistake, and that *thob* is the correct form.

Comment: Another point is that the uses of the word in "key fob" and "fob off" appear completely unrelated (and have etymologically different origins). So even if somebody knows the right spelling for one of them, it doesn't help them to spell the other. Surprisingly, Google finds extremely few instances of "thob off".

Comment: There's a lot of claims here but almost none are referenced.

Answer (score 6):

I get about 1000 times as many results on Google for "key fob" as "key thob". [Google n-grams doesn't list a single occurrence of key thob](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=key%20fob,%20key%20thob&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

[image]

I've never heard it used in any context, historical or otherwise; I suspect it's a mistake.

Comment: Searching for 'key thob' yields 1.1 million results. Link: http://www.google.com/search?q=key+thob&nfpr=1 Searching for 'key fob' yields 7.7 million results. Link: http://www.google.com/search?q=key+fob - That's not 7 times as many, not 1000 times. The lack of it being used in a book may simply mean whenever it's come up during editing it's been decided to use fob. That doesn't speak for the social trend though, only the published trend.

Comment: @glowcoder: the number of results reported by Google on the first page is *wildly* inaccurate. The actual number could be several orders of magnitude smaller or larger (though it's generally smaller). You cannot draw *any* conclusions based on that number.

Comment: @martha Thanks for that information. I'll keep that in mind in the future!

Comment: Also note that I used quotes which reduces the number of results in both cases.

Comment: Google N-Grams only looks at published sources, which are vastly more likely to have the correct spelling. Ngrams are useless for catching this sort of mistake in the wild.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: That's why I gave results for Google as well as Google n-grams.

Answer (score 3):

*Fob* is correct.  It comes from the term for a watch fob, a dangle or ornament that hung from your watch chain.  Key fob, a device or ornament that hung from your car or door key, came to mean key chain.  Then car manufacturers started using it for the auto-lock device that hangs from your keychain.  The security key fob looks like the car start device, so people called it a key fob, especially as many people used to hang it from their keychains.

As for the *f* vs *th* sound, my husband used to pronounce the city of Philadelphia as Philadel**th**ia, as he could not discern the difference in sound.  So it happens in other words as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Thob** is a word, but is not an English word. It is Arabic and appears in several related languages.

> In the north the minimum dress is a long shirt (thob), worn over
> trousers called (sarwal) from the Persian shalvãr.
>
> Languages of Dress in the Middle East *By Bruce Ingham, Nancy Lindisfarne-Tapper*

This will account for the appearance of "thob" in an internet search.

Comment: _In a pedantic tone_ : "This will account for _some_ of the appearances of 'thob' in an internet search."

Answer (score 0):

I first heard of this object when I had an automobile with a "Car Alarm." They gave me a small device to lock/unlock the car, etc. When they handed it to me, they said "This is the "fob" for the car alarm. I had never heard the word before, but I had also never owned a device like the one that I was then holding in my hand before.

So, as far as I am concerned, the word is "fob" NOT "thob" (which I have NEVER heard before.)

NOTE: Even in typing this comment, the computer's spell-checker has flagged the word "thob." So, apparently it has NEVER heard of it either!